# Minimal `Gemfile/Gemfile.lock` for Heroku environment

Tags: ruby, heroku, gemfile

I’m updating the environment on Heroku and one of the [buildpack](https://github.com/thoughtbot/heroku-buildpack-mysql) we use is based on Ruby, which is no longer available by default in the [new `heroku-22` environment/stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-22-stack) (nor required by our PHP app).

[From the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-22-stack#upgrade-notes):

> [...] end users should add the Ruby buildpack prior to the buildpack in question (they will also need to ensure minimal `Gemfile` / `Gemfile.lock` files exist, so that the Ruby buildpack passes detection).

However I have no clue what those files should include as I have zero experience with Ruby. What would be a valid set of minimal `Gemfile`s to trigger Ruby installation on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

It turns out an empty `Gemfile` is not enough and a `Gemfile.lock` is actually required as well.

```bash
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. heroku/python
       2. heroku/ruby
       3. https://github.com/thoughtbot/heroku-buildpack-mysql
       4. heroku/php
       5. heroku/nodejs
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
-----> Stack has changed from heroku-20 to heroku-22, clearing cache
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing python-3.10.8
-----> Installing pip 22.2.2, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting supervisor
         Downloading supervisor-4.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (749 kB)
       Installing collected packages: supervisor
       Successfully installed supervisor-4.2.4
-----> Ruby app detected
grep: /tmp/build_bebc9aa2/Gemfile.lock: No such file or directory
-----> Compiling Ruby/NoLockfile
!
!     Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in.
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
!     Push failed
```

An empty `Gemfile` will trigger the Ruby installation, however the `heroku/ruby` package itself [does require](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby) a lock file.

> The buildpack will detect your app as Ruby if it has a `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files in the root directory.

After some trial and error I figure out the following files work:

```rb
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

```rb
# Gemfile.lock
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

The Gemfile.lock can also be auto-generated by running `bundle install` (after installing bundle)

Comment: "a `Gemfile.lock` is actually required as well"—did you try it without one? [The documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#general-support-activation) explicitly says that an empty `Gemfile` should work for a project without Ruby dependencies: "Even if an application has no gem dependencies it should include an empty `Gemfile` to document that your app has no gem dependencies." And [the `bin/detect` script in the source code](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/83da2a7651f97b5354900144a57d6c5c53862269/bin/detect#L14-L19) only checks for `Gemfile`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed those docs, which say the `Gemfile` will trigger the Ruby installation, however the `heroku/ruby` package itself does require a lock file. I'll update my answer to include these datails

Comment: I'd love a reference for that. The [`bin/detect` script](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/83da2a7651f97b5354900144a57d6c5c53862269/bin/detect#L14-L19) I linked to previously is the script that determines whether an app is compatible with the `heroku/ruby` buildpack. This one only looks for a file called `Gemfile` in the root directory.

Comment: I ran into this exact issue and can confirm that Heroku build failed if I didn't include a Gemfile.lock. Here's the error message from Heroku: `remote:  !     Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in.`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use that buildpack at all. It's ancient, and third-party buildpacks are always a bit questionable, even if it's just because they often stop getting updated.

Here's what it claims to do:

> This is a [Heroku buildpack](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) for vendoring just the `mysql` binary from the `mysql-client-core` deb package.

If you just need a `mysql` binary, you can use [the apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) to install it without worrying about Ruby or anything like that.

1. Add it as your first buildpack:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
   ```
2. Create an `Aptfile` in the root directory of your project that lists [the Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fmysql&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any) you wish to install, e.g.

   ```
   mysql-client-core-8.0
   ```

   Note that the buildpack does not do dependency resolution. If any packages you list have their own dependencies you may have to list them explicitly.
3. Commit, and redeploy.

You should see the Ubuntu packages you listed get installed before your main buildpack runs.

---

In any case, if you really want to make your application compatible with the Ruby buildpack you should be able to simply [include an empty `Gemfile` in the root of your project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#general-support-activation):

> The Heroku Ruby Support will be applied to applications only when the application has a `Gemfile` in the root directory. Even if an application has no gem dependencies it should include an empty `Gemfile` to document that your app has no gem dependencies.

A `Gemfile.lock` is not required.

Note that you'll need to [manually add the buildpacks you require](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app). I believe you'll want Ruby first, then the MySQL buildpack in your question, then whatever language your application is written in, which appears to be PHP:

```bash
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php  # Main buildpack; we insert others before it below
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/ruby
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 https://github.com/thoughtbot/heroku-buildpack-mysql.git
heroku buildpacks
# => Should print the buildpacks in the expected order
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris but unfortunately I do need that package because it is ancient, we are still running MySQL 5.7

Comment: Isn't the client backwards-compatible?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem like, last time I tried si.ply updating the version it broke something, and haven't had time (or need) to dig further yet.

Comment: You're going to have more and more headaches unless you upgrade your database. [MySQL 5.7 isn't officially supported on anything newer than Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://www.mysql.com/de/support/supportedplatforms/database.html). Why are you using the Heroku 22 stack if you have such an old dependency?

Comment: I 100% agree Chris, we should update engine version, however that will need to wait till we have a more compelling reason. `heroku-22` will update Node and PHP. Right now I just need to have Ruby installed on Heroku, which will fix the MySQL compatibility with our old databases :)

Comment: @Stefano, while that doesn't seem like a sustainable solution, please see the note at the end of my updated answer.